# GFCI to light not working

Tags: electrical

I put a gfci outlet in my front yard for use during christmas time for lights and such. i ran it to on my front porch light so it only turns on when my front porch light is on. i also added to the gfci a light about 20 feet away so that it lights up a dark area. I turned my breaker on and the gfci works but the light doesn't turn on. why is this happening? Ive tested and reset the gfci. unfortunately it got too dark to work on the wires. what could be the problem as to why there is no light going to the light post?

Comment: Pictures of the wiring may help. ( Also always provide a location as local regulations vary widely )

Comment: Some sketches/photos of how you have it wired currently would be very helpful.

Comment: Thank you guys for the help it turned out the black wires weren't touching they somehow slipped out when i pushed the light on the pole

Comment: @Anthony -- post that comment as an answer and I'll upvote it :)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the OP's problem was caused by a loose connection that slipped out when he attempted to fit the light fixture to its pole, as per his comment:

> Thank you guys for the help it turned out the black wires weren't touching they somehow slipped out when i pushed the light on the pole

Answer (score 0):

Check the ground on the new light. It could be tied in in a way that trips the gfi. Also if the wire is getting wet to the new location.

Comment: There is no water...checked the ground on the light everything is wired corectly on the light end...the only thing that i could think of is the ground coming from the light is grounded onto the weather proof box where the gfci is at, im not sure if that makes a difference...